# Division in Projection Matrices

Tags: math, matrix, vector, 3d, projection

Disclaimer: This question is not the same question as other projection matrix questions.

So Projection Matrices are 4x4 Matrices that are multiplied with 4D vectors to flatten them onto a 2D plane. Like this one:

1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0
0  0  0  0
0  0  1  0

But in the explanation, it says that the x and y coordinates of the vector are divided by Z. But I don't understand how this works because each part of the matrix that is multiplied by Z is 0. A comment in another question on this subject said, "The hardware does this for you." And I didn't quite get what it meant by that. Thank you in advance!

Comment: the perspective divide is not part of matrix multiplication... its done after it on the result either by your code or directly by HW or gfx lib... Also the divide is done by either `z` or `w` value of the result (depends on the projection matrix used) see [How to use face normal for back-face culling in perspective projection scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67175750/2521214) look for `// perspective divide by w + scale x,y to pixels` in the code

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for clarifying it @Spektre!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confounded by this nomenclature issue, too. Here is a bit better explanation in regards to Vulkan: https://matthewwellings.com/blog/the-new-vulkan-coordinate-system/

> After the programmable vertex stage a set of fixed function vertex operations are run. *During this process* your homogeneous coordinates in clip space are divided by wc

Clearly, calling those matrices *projection* matrices is very misleading if the actual perspective correction isn't actually done by them. :)