# How do I implement Backface Culling into my 3D engine?

Tags: c++, math, 3d, rendering, sfml

I am trying to implement backface culling into my 3d engine but it doesn't seem to work
I followed javidx9's video on it which was the only one i could find on backface culling,
but it did not work  and I do not know why.

The only thing that is done correctly (or so i think)
is the normal calculation
so that is not neccessary to add unless my calculations are wrong.
The only thing i need right now is what condition allows the triangle to be drawn

I kind of understand how it works and the formulas behind but I am unable to code it.
What I would like to receive as an answer that shows me how i can implement it using code

Here's the code needed

```
triangle &listtri = tridrawlist[i]; // the triangle that is going through the culling process
vec3 norm; // the surface normal of the triangle
 
line = listtri.vpos2 - listtri.vpos; // vpos means view space (camera space) position if you were wondering
line2 = listtri.vpos3 - listtri.vpos;
norm = line.cross(line2); // cross() is a cross product function (which works) and in this case the first vector is line and the second is lin2

// here is where you write the condition / variables needed for you to solve the problem
```

Comment: Why does your post read like you're asking about a homework assignment? (mind you, in itself there's nothing wrong wish asking about homework, but you do need to make it clear whether it is or not if you're going to show code that has things like "here is where you write the condition". _We_ don't have to write anything, _you_ apparently do, though)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67176014/2521214

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you should do at first is, confirmation about the normal vector calculation result.
For example, render it and check whether the normal direct to inside or outside direction.

If you confirmed all normal vectors direct to outside direction correctly, "Culling" is just checking whether normal directs to camera side or not, like:

```
vec3 CameraFrontDirectionalVector;  //e.g. (0,0,1) if Z is front
vec3 norm = (Normal Vector of the Triangle)

if( DotProduct( norm, CameraFrontDirectionalVector ) < 0 )
{//norm directs to camera side
  /* Draw the triangle */
  ...
}
```